# saving bitmap from arraylist to SD card - saved file unreadable

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, bitmap, save

My situation is as follows: I'm saving multiple bitmaps from an arraylist to a specific folder in my devices SD Card (with success), however, the saved file- when clicked- prompts a message from the phone, stating: "Unable to find application to perform this action." The file size of this file is proportional to that of the bitmap image being saved, so I'm a bit confused, as the device has no problems opening image files, yet cannot open (or identifiy) these as a media file.

Question: What would cause the saved image file (presuming that I have saved it correctly) to exhibit this type of behavior in a device, and how should I resolve this issue?

Extra: the thumbnail of the file is the system provided thumbnail of the two papers on top of each other. The arraylist is being passed from one activity to its current one where the method provided is supplied.

Here is the method invoking the saving of the files to the specified folder /filesdestination:

```
private void saveImages(){
// to retrieve bitmaps
    ArrayList<Bitmap> images = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("images key");
//to retrieve bitmaps and save in specific order, while also naming them in that order
    int loopVal = 0;
    int postVal = 9;
    while ( loopVal < 9) {
        Bitmap Image = images.get(loopVal);
    try {

        String filedestination = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()  + "/filedestination"); 
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        File file = new File(filedestination, postVal + ".post_order" +  ".jpg" + timeStamp);
        File picfile = file;
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
            Image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);      
            fos.close();



    } catch (Throwable e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    postVal--;
    loopVal++;

    }


}
```

Any insight would be appreciated,

-Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it cannot read the file type because the timestamp is after the file extension jpg and you are also compressing it as a png, so you might want to change either or, something like this

```
File file = new File(filedestination, postVal + timeStamp +".post_order" +  ".png");
```

Comment: This worked! I now know how significant the placement of .png of .jpg is in terms of cross-application readability, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are saving a .jpg file compressed as a PNG. That can make the image reader app to misbehave.

Either change `Image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);`

to

`Image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);`

**or** change

`File file = new File(filedestination, postVal + ".post_order" +  ".jpg" + timeStamp);`

to

`File file = new File(filedestination, postVal + ".post_order" +  ".png" + timeStamp);`

Comment: I tried this, but the same instances had occurred :/

Comment: Yes, I missed the fact that the timestamp was after the extension, like the other answer point out. :)